# Variable scoping with an except block: Difference between Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I came across a weird difference with local variable scopes between Python 2.7 and Python 3.7.

Consider this artificial script `unboundlocalexception.py` (I realize that I could just have used an else-block after except, but I extracted this example from a longer function):

```
def foo():
  arithmetic_error = None
  try:
    y = 1.0 / 0
  except ZeroDivisionError as arithmetic_error:
    print("I tried to divide by zero")

  if arithmetic_error is None:
    print("Correct division")

foo()
```

Under Python 2 it works as I expected it to:

```
$ python2 unboundlocalexception.py 
I tried to divide by zero
```

But, surprisingly, under Python 3 an UnboundLocalError is raised!

```
$ python3 unboundlocalexception.py 
I tried to divide by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unboundlocalexception.py", line 11, in <module>
    foo()
  File "unboundlocalexception.py", line 8, in foo
    if arithmetic_error is None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'arithmetic_error' referenced before assignment
```

Is this difference documented anywhere?

Comment: I am too surprised by this. Trying to figure out this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 exception deletes variable in enclosing scope for unknown reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268892/python-3-exception-deletes-variable-in-enclosing-scope-for-unknown-reason)

Comment: That's it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour was introduced in Python 3, to prevent reference cycles, because the exception target - `arithmetic_error` in the question - keeps a reference to the traceback.

From the [Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)

> When an exception has been assigned using as target, it is cleared at
>   the end of the except clause. This is as if

```
except E as N:
    foo
```

> was translated to

```
except E as N:
    try:
        foo
    finally:
        del N
```

> This means the exception must be assigned to a different name to be
>   able to refer to it after the except clause. Exceptions are cleared
>   because with the traceback attached to them, they form a reference
>   cycle with the stack frame, keeping all locals in that frame alive
>   until the next garbage collection occurs.

This was originally documented in [PEP3110](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/#id22).

Comment: It really looks like you **copied** this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29268974. Instead of copying you should just flag the question as a duplicate ;) And give credit to the person who really answered....

Comment: I simply looked at the docmentation, and quoted it - I wasn't aware of the other answer when I answered.  But since you have found a good duplicate, I will close this question.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco   Or at least I would have done, had not, not user chepner beaten me to it.